# XSL sort numbers from different nodes

Tags: xslt, sorting

I need to construct a string from numbers located in different nodes in my xml source, but the caveats are that the datarate nodes order will be random and the starting number has to be start with at least 600.  If there is no 600, then start with 800.

```
<datarate rate="200" />
<datarate rate="600" />
<datarate rate="300" />
<datarate rate="400" />
<datarate rate="800" />
<datarate rate="1000" />

http://example.com/src/600/800/
```

I've tried sorting based on groups, but to no avail.  Anyone out there have an idea?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you want the string to look like? Also, are you using XSLT/XPath 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 2 you can do this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="//datarate[number(@rate) ge 600]">
      <xsl:sort select="@rate" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="@rate"/>
      <xsl:if test="not(position() eq last())">
         <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: you would still need to do some if/then/else around the '600' or '800' condition, right? and having XSLT 2.0 you could leverage the `separator` of the `xsl:value-of` and don't do the XSLT 1.0 idiom around `position() !- last()`

Comment: @Pavel Veller: What if/then/else do you mean? The result as given is "600, 800, 1000". Also, I dont't quite see how `separator` would help, since each `xsl:value-of` is operating on a single item.

Comment: you're right about the `xsl:value-of` within the `for-each`. the if/then/else is related to @hybrid9 requirement `if there is no 600, then start with 800`. I figured if there's no 600, 650 or 750 wouldn't make it

Comment: @Pavel Veller: The solution given works regardless of whether the value 600 is present or not.

Comment: it does, until there is `650` in there somewhere :) just modify the input a little bit. maybe I misinterpreted the requirements about the `800` and `600` threshold. Anyway, it doesn't really matter. The solution is still pretty straightforward either way.

Comment: @Pavel Veller: The solution given works regardless of whether the value 650 is present or not. Since you keep implying the solution is somehow wrong: I will readily accept any bug you can demonstrate using a concrete XML file. For the benefit of the original poster, yourself, myself, and all future readers, please actually test your assumption before claiming the solution is incorrect, and then post your concrete findings here.

Comment: I did. please take a look at @Dimitre answer above. we had the same discussion like I am having here with you. if you change the original input to have `650` instead of `600` your solution will print `650` in the result. The requirement said that if there's no `600` in the document then the threshold should be set to `800`. Your solution doesn't do that as you "statically" define a threshold to always be `ge 600`. I hope it makes sense. if it doesn't, let's just agree to disagree :)

Comment: Given his example, I would say he's using "800" as a synonym for "the next number greater than 600 in the data". But I guess the original poster should comment...

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks!  I actually had to rewrite for XSLT 1, but still worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you knew the threshold number upfront you could do a very simple transform like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//datarate">
            <xsl:sort select="@rate" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="datarate[@rate &lt; 600]"/>

    <xsl:template match="datarate">
        [<xsl:value-of select="@rate"/>]
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Since you need to check if there's a `600` and use `800` as your threshold if no `600` found, you could it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

   <xsl:variable name="threshold">
       <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="//datarate[@rate = 600]">600</xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>800</xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="//datarate">
           <xsl:sort select="@rate" data-type="number"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>  

   <xsl:template match="datarate[@rate &lt; $threshold]"/>

   <xsl:template match="datarate">
       [<xsl:value-of select="@rate"/>]
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the event there might be neither a `600` nor a `800` you might want to add some more logic to the `$threshold` variable declaration.

p.s. Having no details about how you would like your string constructed I just printed the `@rate` values enclosed in `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

**This short and simple transformation** (no explicit conditional instruction used at all -- no `xsl:choose`, no `xsl:when`, no `xsl:otherwise`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <t>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
     <xsl:sort select="@rate" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </t>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "datarate
     [not(@rate >= 600)
     or
      not(../*[@rate = 600]) and not(@rate >= 800)
     ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped into a single top element to be made well-formed):

```
<t>
    <datarate rate="200" />
    <datarate rate="600" />
    <datarate rate="300" />
    <datarate rate="400" />
    <datarate rate="800" />
    <datarate rate="1000" />
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t>
   <datarate rate="600"/>
   <datarate rate="800"/>
   <datarate rate="1000"/>
</t>
```

**when applied on the following, slightly changed XML document** (no rate of 600, but rates of 601 and 650):

```
<t>
    <datarate rate="200" />
    <datarate rate="601" />
    <datarate rate="650" />
    <datarate rate="300" />
    <datarate rate="400" />
    <datarate rate="800" />
    <datarate rate="1000" />
</t>
```

**again the correct result is produced:**

```
<t>
   <datarate rate="800"/>
   <datarate rate="1000"/>
</t>
```

Comment: nice... only when you change your first input to have `650` instead of `600` it will print it out. I understood original requirements so that if there's no `600`, the new threshold is `800`. You will have to have a conditional in there somewhere :) will you not?

Comment: I understood the requirement that if there is 600 and 800 then the result will start from 800.

Comment: @Pavel Veller: OK, seems your understanding of the problem was correct -- I fixed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @PavelVeller: To answer your question: as you can see, I have corrected the solution and it doesn't contain even a single XSLT conditional instruction. So, yes, this *is* possible.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev This is a great script which I'll actually need in the future.  Thanks for taking the time to help me out.  I will actually use this and built on top of the marked solution below.  Thanks!

Comment: @hybrid9: You are welcome. If this is the solution you'd really be using, why not bother to accept it? :)